# How to get data from Component to Another Component with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the data in the UserOrderCartPage and move it to the UserOrderPage but the only thing that moves is the state description, everything else is undefined..

How can I get all the data that is in the UserOrderCartPage and to be entered into the UserOrderPage please help me

App.js

```
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState([
        {
          id: 1,
          user: "mukti",
          pesanan: [
            {
              id: 1,
              slug: "nasi-goreng",
              nama: "Nasi Goreng",
              kategori: ["makanan", "populer"],
              harga: 15000,
              deskripsi:
                "Nasi goreng adalah sebuah makanan berupa nasi yang digoreng dan diaduk dalam minyak goreng, margarin, atau mentega. Biasanya ditambah kecap manis, bawang merah, bawang putih, asam jawa, lada dan bumbu-bumbu lainnya; seperti telur, ayam, dan kerupuk.",
              image: "https://food-order-app.irfanhafizh.repl.co/nasi-goreng.png",
              jumlahPesanan: 3,
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              slug: "mie-goreng",
              nama: "Mie Goreng",
              kategori: ["makanan", "populer"],
              harga: 10000,
              deskripsi:
                "Mie goreng berarti 'mie yang digoreng' adalah hidangan mie yang dimasak dengan digoreng tumis khas Indonesia. Mi goreng juga populer dan juga digemari di Malaysia, dan Singapura.",
              image: "https://food-order-app.irfanhafizh.repl.co/mie-goreng.png",
              jumlahPesanan: 2,
            },
          ],
          status: "cooking",
          keterangan: "gak pake sayuran, pedas",
          totalHargaPesanan: 100000,
        },
      ]);
    
      const pesananBaru = (
        id,
        user,
        pesanan,
        status,
        keterangan,
        totalHargaPesanan
      ) => {
        const pesananBaru = {
          id: id,
          user: user,
          pesanan: pesanan,
          status: status,
          keterangan: keterangan,
          totalHargaPesanan: totalHargaPesanan,
        };
        setOrders([...orders, pesananBaru]);
      };

          <Route
            exact
            path="/:user/keranjang-saya"
            element={
              <UserOrderCartPage
                cartItems={cartItems}
                handleAddProduct={handleAddProduct}
                handleRemoveProduct={handleRemoveProduct}
                handleCartClearance={handleCartClearance}
                pesananBaru={pesananBaru}
              />
            }
          />
```

UserOrderCartPage.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

const UserOrderCartPage = ({
  cartItems,
  handleAddProduct,
  handleRemoveProduct,
  handleCartClearance,
  pesananBaru,
}) => {
  const totalHarga = cartItems.reduce(
    (harga, item) => harga + item.quantity * item.harga,
    0
  );
  const [id, setId] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [pesanan, setPesanan] = useState([]);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("");
  const [keterangan, setKeterangan] = useState("");
  const [totalHargaPesanan, setTotalHargaPesanan] = useState();

  console.log(id, user, pesanan, status, keterangan, totalHargaPesanan);

  return (
    <>
      <form
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          pesananBaru(id, user, pesanan, status, keterangan, totalHargaPesanan);
          setId(2);
          setUser(localStorage.getItem("usernameData"));
          setPesanan({ cartItems });
          setStatus("Cooking");
          setTotalHargaPesanan(totalHarga);
        }}
      >
        {cartItems.length === 0 && <h1>Keranjang Pesanan kamu Kosong!</h1>}
        {cartItems.length >= 1 && (
          <button onClick={handleCartClearance}>Hapus Semua</button>
        )}
        <div>
          {cartItems.map((item) => (
            <div key={item.id}>
              <img src={item.image} alt={item.nama} />
              <h1>{item.nama}</h1>
              <button type="button" onClick={() => handleAddProduct(item)}>
                +
              </button>
              <button type="button" onClick={() => handleRemoveProduct(item)}>
                -
              </button>
              {item.quantity} * Rp. {item.harga.toLocaleString("id-ID")},-
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        {cartItems.length >= 1 && (
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Masukan Keterangan"
            value={keterangan}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setKeterangan(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
        )}
        {cartItems.length >= 1 && (
          <h1>Total Harga : Rp. {totalHarga.toLocaleString("id-ID")},-</h1>
        )}
        {cartItems.length >= 1 && <button type="submit">Pesan Sekarang</button>}
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserOrderCartPage;
```

UserOrderPage.js

```
const UserOrderPage = ({ orders }) => {
  console.log(orders);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Ini halaman Pesanan Saya</h1>
      {orders.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>Pesanan : {item.user}</p>
          <p>Jumlah Pesanan: {item.jumlahPesanan}</p>
          <p>Status: {item.status}</p>
          <p>Keterangan: {item.keterangan}</p>
          <p>
            Total Harga: Rp. {item.totalHarga}
            ,-
          </p>
          <hr />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserOrderPage;
```

Comment: are you calling UserOrderPage component from UserOrderPage module ? please provide code how are you calling UserOrderPage from UserOrderPage module

Comment: <Route
            exact
            path="/:user/pesanan-saya"
            element={<UserOrderPage pesanan={pesanan} />}
          />